# Way to calculate a column based off of a another column after filter is set?

Tags: 2013, workflow, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

[image]

This is the example after I filtered on what I need to calculate.

JPP: = 14681369    WC/Site Code:= 386746   Bill =$1,138 ANOTHER Invoice is
JPP: = 15091824B   WC/Site Code:= 386734   Bill =$21,874 the OTHER invoice is
JPP: = 16966035    WC/Site Code:= 386746   Bill =$569

The additional will look like this since the data above is filtered, There is two costs for wc center 386746, which adds it and same for the other wirecenter. then at the end it will give the total of the invoice as well as total of each separate WC/Site Code

Bill 386746 = $1707
Bill 386734 = $21874

Total Invoice                 $23,581
Is this possible? let me know if you guys would like more clarification. Thank you...

Comment: Can any one help please?

Comment: it requires some serious front-end javascript development. I have documented it in the past to Sum a Calculated Column (see http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum) but your requirement is more complex. Doable because the code on IMGs are reexecuted when you ad-hoc filter a list, something you can not easily achieve with JSlink. But.. takes some coding... I am experienced at this stuff and guess it would take me a day